# Label a teamcity build so that once it is success in dev, same can be deployed on SIT, UAT and PROD

Tags: deployment, teamcity, build-automation, pipeline

I am looking for some process in teamcity similar to tag or label. When I took last successful build from teamcity, I should be able to give a name to that build after doing a successful deployment on DEV environment. I wish to establish an automated process where whenever there is next successful deployment is done, old artifacts are replaced with new one with same label. This will always give me a last successfully deployed development build with same URL. Then I can use this build for SIT deployment. If SIT deployment is successful, same thing I will to with SIT build which further can be used for UAT. Similar thing goes on for UAT and production case.

I was using teamcity REST API and shell scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to setup a canary deployment for your codebase. The answer for this questions does depend on your choice of VCS. (it is easier to do in git which has cheap tagging).

You can do it in 2 ways

1. After you run a succesful deploy, you can `tag` your build state to the vcs with a specific tag like `dev-latest` . You can hook up your SIT targets to have a trigger based on this tag and run whwnever the tag moves to a new state
2. If you are using teamcity, a better way would be to setup **`artefact dependent builds`** . Using this, you can make your SIT build **dependent** on your DEV targets. Whenever your DEV target  is succesful , your SIT target can download the relevant artefacts from the DEV target through dependencies and then proceed with its own chain. You can read more about it [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Dependent+Build)